# Angular JS unable to require another directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having an issue where if I require another directive about the current one i get the following error message

> Error: [$compile:ctreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.10/$compile/ctreq?p0=myApp.pagereel&p1=ngTransclude

Script.js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('viewport', function()
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="viewport" ng-transclude></div>',
        transclude: true,
        replace: true
    }
})

.directive('pagereel', function()
{
    return {
        controller: function ($scope)
        {
            $scope.next =  function (colour)
            {
                if(typeof colour !== 'undefined')
                {

                    $scope.pages.splice($scope.position + 1);
                    $scope.pages.push({colour: colour});
                    $scope.position++;
                }
            },

            $scope.previous = function (colour)
            {
                if(typeof colour !== 'undefined')
                {
                    $scope.pages = $scope.pages.slice(0, 1);
                    $scope.pages.push({colour: colour});
                    $scope.position = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $scope.position--;
                }

            },

            $scope.home = function (colour)
            {
                if(typeof colour !== 'undefined')
                {
                    $scope.pages = [{colour: colour}];
                }

                $scope.position = 0;
            }
        },

        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div class="pagereel" style="right: {{position * 100}}%; width: {{pages.length * 100}}%" ng-transclude></div>',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs)
        {
            scope.position = 0
            scope.pages = [{colour: 'green'}];
        }
    }
})

.directive('page', ['$compile', function($compile)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<section class="page" style="background: {{page.colour}}; width: {{ 100 / pages.length }}%" ng-transclude></section>',
        replace: true,
        scope: true,
        transclude: true,
    }
}])

.directive('next', function(){

    return {
        require: "pagereel",
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<button ng-transclude></button>',
        replace: true,
        transclude:true,
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, pagereelCtrl) 
        {
            console.log(pagereelCtrl)
            element.bind("click", function()
            {
                pagereelCtrl.next(attrs.colour)
            })
        }   
    };
});
```

Html:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>

    <viewport>
        <pagereel>
            <page ng-repeat="page in pages"><next color="blue">Next</next></page>
        </pagereel>
    </viewport>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I allow  to access the function "next" in the controller of "pagereel"?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Edited to include the implied question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you would like to access the `next` function of the `pagereelCtrl` you may not bind the funciton to `$scope`. Bind the function you want to call to `this`:

```
this.next =  function (colour) {
    if(typeof colour !== 'undefined') {
        $scope.pages.splice($scope.position + 1);
        $scope.pages.push({colour: colour});
         $scope.position++;
    }
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks, this formed part of my answer, I had to add ^ before the name